# How know the version of Silverlight - Project Visual Studio 2012

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, version, project, guid

I have a project with Silverlight and when I saw th code of the project file with notepad I have this code:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
```

But I would like to know the version of Silverlight that I'm using but I don't know how...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set or view the Silverlight target version of your project, on the properties page, Silverlight tab, there is a dropdown called Target Silverlight Version.  The project file entries will look like so:

```
<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Silverlight</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v5.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<SilverlightVersion>$(TargetFrameworkVersion)</SilverlightVersion>
```

Comment: I guess this is about visual studio 2010+. For visual studio 2008 I had to open the .csproj file through notepad and search for all 'silverlight' references. I managed to find a compiler reference of silverlight version 3.